# FormClosingEventArgs error?

Tags: c#

```
public void AltF4(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

It is telling me that `Object` has no definition for `OnClosing`. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: So what is the class of `base`? Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The emphasis is on **minimal**.

Comment: You should be overriding the OnFormClosing method.  If this code isn't in a form class (doesn't look like it based on the error), then what are you trying to close or prevent from closing?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you may try something like:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.CloseReason != CloseReason.WindowsShutDown 
    && e.CloseReason != CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall 
    && e.CloseReason != CloseReason.FormOwnerClosing )
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
    base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

Hope this may help.